# Getting null for OS system property when Run As -> Maven test in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Have a Maven project with 2 test classes. 
Have a very simple snippet

```
String name = System.getProperty("OS");
System.out.println("OS name is " + name);
```

When I run the individual test class as JUnit Test in Eclipse, get
OS name is Windows 10.

When I run the project (both test classes) as Maven test in Eclipse, get
OS name is null

What causes the difference and how to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be [System.getProperty("os.name");](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)?

Comment: Thank you, Freddy. You are right. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

As Freddy wrote, the correct statement is

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

I'm writing this to indicate that the question is answered and closed.